# What's wrong with the ranges for my variable?

Tags: c

I have almost zero experience with programming but I have to write a simple C program which calculates the specific heat (Cp) as a function of temperature T.
The temperature range is split in smaller ranges in order to get accurate values for Cp.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>

int main()
{    
    float T, cp1, cp2, cp3, cp4, cp5, cp6, cp7, cp8;                     /*variables */  

    printf( "Please enter temperature in Kelvin\n" );  /* Asks for temperature */
    scanf( "%f", &T );

    cp1=1.67662377469456E-11*pow(T,6.)-4.1197828092268E-08*pow(T,5.)+0.0000418869586791152*pow(T,4.)-0.0225003443462658*pow(T,3.)+6.72987826198519*pow(T,2.)-1062.18721205927*T+73195.8387080729;
    cp2=0.00525246395569212*pow(T,4.)-12.9485474717992*pow(T,3.)+11970.600895997*pow(T,2.)-4918448.82178862*T+757825839.152518;
    cp3=6.63085194968153*pow(T,4.)-17170.4000395659*pow(T,3.)+16673480.6519115*pow(T,2.)-7196031423.69135*T+1164647463146.08;
    cp4=-68.0819524480029*pow(T,5.)+222554.556013276*pow(T,4.)-291004129.724188*pow(T,3.)+190252342532.153*pow(T,2.)-62191220562433.3*T+8131793672657510;
    cp5=9974.74747475981*pow(T,3.)-19674382.9004572*pow(T,2.)+12935329616.4157*T-2834856258114.32;
    cp6=-4.14962557364299E-07*pow(T,6.)+0.000462300031790556*pow(T,5.)-0.0310330512189478*pow(T,4.)+62.8598088326175*pow(T,3.)-189691.032172151*pow(T,2.)+77129922.3433911*T-4056849697.67083;
    cp7=1.47773054803578E-08*pow(T,6.)-0.0000239186385308144*pow(T,5.)+0.00563616606939476*pow(T,4.)+1.50391266948934*pow(T,3.)+9118.7111011683*pow(T,2.)-8897122.07353999*T+2172208386.41784;
    cp8=-4.6626284146362E-08*pow(T,5.)+0.000192659539297423*pow(T,4.)-0.318404373982708*pow(T,3.)+263.141418952148*pow(T,2.)-108775.736711323*T+18001673.992402;


    if (T>=280. && T<=599.9) {                      /* 1st temp range !!! If 599.9 is entered, the program calculates cp2 instead of cp1*/ 
        printf ("1st range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp1);                    /* returns cp1 */
    }
    else if (T>599.9 && T<=646.8) {            /* 2nd temp range */ 
        printf("2nd range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp2);                 /* returns cp2 */
    }
    else if (T>646.8 && T<=651.2) {            /* 3rd temp range !!! If 651.2 is entered, the program calculates cp4 instead of cp3*/ 
        printf("3rd range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp3);                 /* returns cp3 */
    }
    else if (T>651.2 && T<=655.8) {            /* 4th temp range */ 
        printf("4th range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp4);                 /* returns cp4 */
    }
    else if (T>655.8 && T<=656.6) {            /* 5th temp range */ 
        printf("5th range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp5);                 /* returns cp5 */
    }
    else if (T>656.6 && T<=662.) {            /* 6th temp range */ 
        printf("6th range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp6);                 /* returns cp6 */
    }
    else if (T>662. && T<=700.) {            /* 7th temp range */ 
        printf("7th range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp7);                 /* returns cp7 */
    }
    else if (T>700. && T<=900.) {            /* 8th temp range */ 
        printf("8th range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp8);                 /* returns cp8 */
    }
    else {
        printf("Cp= 4180 J/kgK");     /* Executed if no other statement is */
    }

  return 0;
}
```

The code may not be elegant but it works except for the 1st range and the 3rd range.

For the first range

```
if (T>=280. && T<=599.9) {                      /* 1st temp range If 599.9 is entered, the program calculates cp2 instead of cp1*/ 
        printf ("1st range Cp= %.6f J/kgK",cp1);                    /* returns cp1 */
    }
```

if I enter T equal to 599.9 the calculation for value Cp is done with the equation cp2 instead of cp1.
The same happens for the 3rd temperature range. If I enter T equal to 651.2, Cp is calculated with cp4 instead cp3.
I don't understand why. The rest works just fine.
The code is compiled with portable Dev-C++ 5.11.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's to do with *floating point imprecision* and your mixing `double` and `float` types.

`599.9` is a double precision floating point literal, `T` is a `float`.

The comparison `T <= 599.9` will appear to misbehave for certain values of `T`. `T` will be promoted to a `double` prior to the expression being evaluated. It will retain the imprecision introduced by it being a `float` since the C standard mandates that *all* `float`s must be *exactly* representable by a `double`.

You'd get more explainable boundaries if you were to either (i) use `599.9f` as the bounds (that's how you write a `float` literal), or (ii) use `double` for your types.

But the floating point imprecision issues still hold: not all numbers can be represented exactly in that scheme: 599.9 is one such number under IEEE754. Assuming your compiler uses IEEE754, your specific problem arises because 599.9 in an IEEE754 32 bit is greater than 599.9 by a larger amount that 599.9 as an IEEE754 64 bit.

Comment: With higher precision you may only be moving the problem further into more insignificant digits – there is no guarantee `599.9` can be represented exactly as a double either. That is, it may still round up or down at will in a direction unknown (for the OP at least). Suggestion: change `if (T>=280. && T<=599.9)` to `if (T>=280. && T<600.0)`.

Comment: I followed your advice (599.9f) and now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that unfortuantely, computers can't 100% accurately represent every number.

If you print out your value of T after you read it in, you actually get 599.9000024 which is of course larger than 599.9 and uses the 3rd statement.

You can temporarily get around this using double types instead of float which has a higher precision.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably because you are converting floats and doubles, and thereby introducing rounding errors. It is sort of a rule of thumb that `float1 == float2` is never reliable. And the same for doubles.

Comment: Not reliable? Floating point comparisons are not random. It's just that people have wrong expectations.

Comment: The comparisons are reliable, and wether or not you can do them while making sense is dependant on the actual number. There are values which can be finitely represented in both. The pitfall here is that people have false expectations when dealing with them.

Comment: Well, that's sort of what i meant. If you know your business, go ahead, but if you don't, dont trust `==` ;)